# Why when this URL for calling runs, it shows nil instead of the number in my UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Currently I am working on an app and when a phone number is typed into my UITextField it is called after pressing a notification action by running a URL. But the problem is that it is calling a phone number that says 645 instead of any phone number that I type in, I figured out that it is using 645 because it is a default to a nil phone number. How do I fix this nil value so that it is actually the phone number typed into my UITextField? Any answers would be awesome. Thank you! Here is my code:

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


//After notification AlertView (Sending into call)
func showAlertAppDelegate(title : String,message : String,buttonTitle1 : String, buttonTitle2: String, window: UIWindow){

    //AlertView
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        //Action 'Go!'

        let alertActionGo = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle1, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
            UIAlertAction in

            let actualNumber = phoneNumbered?.text
            print(actualNumber as Any)

            if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(actualNumber)") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
            }

        }

        let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel){
            UIAlertAction in

        }

            alert.addAction(alertActionGo)
            alert.addAction(alertActionCancel)

    window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




//Main Stuff
var window: UIWindow?






//Setting up notification view

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(accepted, error) in
        if !accepted {
            print("Notification access denied.")
        }
    }

    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "call", title: "Enter Call", options: [.foreground])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

    return true
}




//Schedule notification

func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Call"
    content.body = "Its time for your call!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "logo", url: url, options: nil)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        } catch {
            print("The attachment was not loaded.")
        }
    }

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}




}


let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? ViewController

var phoneNumbered = delegate?.phoneNumber



//If Notification Action is pressed
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,     didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


    if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {
        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: "Enter Call", message: "Are you sure?", buttonTitle1: "Go", buttonTitle2: "Cancel", window: self.window!)
















    }


}
}
```

Comment: What have you done to confirm phoneNumbered contains the full number in showAlertAppDelegate? And why is it not a parameter?

Comment: Yes but to repeat the question, what have you done to confirm at the point it is assigned to actualNumber that it contains what you expect it to. Have you  inspected its value in the debugger for example.

Comment: So then how you have set that up, to populate it, share it, access it between the VC and the AppDelegate is incorrect.

Comment: How can anybody show you how to set it up when you have not shown any relevant code? Where's all the rest.

Comment: @Mungbeans I put my full AppDelegate.swift code into it

Comment: This code has numerous errors, particularly around the definition of delegate (which is certainly nil). Fixing this devolves into writing the entire program, which is too broad for Stack Overflow. Your basic error is that by the time the notification fires, the view controller is gone. You need to save its information in the model (UserDefaults would be good here), and read that back when the notification fires.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let actualNumber = phoneNumbered?.text
```

`actualNumber` is of type `String?`. As you note, it's actually nil. So when you interpolate that:

```
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://nil") {
```

The phone number "NIL" is [645](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#Layout_and_characters).

Comment: So how do I fix this nil value so that it is equal to what I type into the UITextField

Comment: Your current code makes little sense. Your definitions of delegate and phonenumberd are circular and almost certainly nil. (You seem to be trying to treat your app delegate as if it were a view controller, which is a mistake I haven't seen before, so it's hard to reverse engineer the other mistakes that probably exist in ViewController.) if you're trying to read a text field in your app delegate, you have a major problem already. I would probably start again, but to debug, walk through the code and check anywhere with ? for nil.